# Displaying result using frame

Tags: jsp, frame

I am trying to create GUI in two frames, left and right. Left frame is used to display forms for user to fill data and the right frame is used to display the result.

What I have done is as follows:

When user click "Simulation" on the menu, program will display forms to be filled by users (there are six forms) in the left frame. At the last form when the user click "Calculate", the program should display the result on the right frame and the form on the left frame must be still visible. But what happen so far is that the result is still displayed in the left frame.

I am using jsp and servlet. Each jsp page call servlet and this servlet call another jsp page. And the last servlet call view.jsp to view the data. I do not know how to direct view.jsp to be displayed in the right frame.

Any body know how to solve my problem? Or are there any other ways to solve that problem (eg. without using frame)?
Can I view the result on the right frame each time the user move to other form (jsp page)?

Thanks,

Iman

Answer (score 0):

You have to use **target attribute of form** tag and give the **right frame name** in that.